# CRUD operations in Android sql

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite, crud

I am just learning SQL on android and following a tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/). Thinks are working fine which are mentioned in tutorial. But I want to use update and delete operation. For this I am using this code. 
For delete

```
Contact contact = (Contact)db.getContact(2);
db.deleteContact(contact);
Log.d("Delete", "Contact Deleted");
```

This function delete all contacts from contacts table. While I want to delete only contact having ID=1

For update

```
Log.d("Update Contact", "Updating Contact...");
Contact contact = (Contact)db.getContact(2);
contact.setName("Updated Name");
contact.setPhoneNumber("333444");
db.updateContact(contact);
```

And this code updates all contacts in database with "Updated Name". However I want to update only the contact having ID 2.
Am I doing something wrong.

Delete function in DatabaseHandler.java

```
public void deleteContact(Contact contact){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID+"+?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getID())});
db.close();
}
```

and Update Function is

```
public int updateContact(Contact contact){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_NAME,contact.getName());
values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());
return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID+"+?", new String [] String.valueOf(contact.getID())});
    }
```

Comment: can you post your updateContact and deleteContact methods?

Comment: @giacomoni Question edited and added.

Comment: yes typo was the culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `deleteContact` method change:

```
db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID+"+?"
```

to:

```
db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID+"=?"
```

and in your updateContact change:

```
return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID+"+?", new String [] String.valueOf(contact.getID())});
```

to:

```
return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID+"=?", new String []{ String.valueOf(contact.getID())});
```

Comment: Hi, for CRUD operations in Android Platform this training site: keikis.org/academy/es/android-index/androd-base-final-projec‌​t. – Zeus Monolitics yesterday